# Scientific publications in Careers CV

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I'm currently in the process of submitting a scientific paper to a congress for publication in their proceedings.

This will be a great point for my CV. I have "tried" to click on "add an article or blog post you’ve written" but it asks me for a URL.

Since scientific papers don't *usually* have a home URL (unless they get indexed by Google Scholar and/or published at IEEE), shouldn't it be possible to add an article the candidate wrote by citing references instead of reporting URL?

Today it's still early to update my CV but I'm still asking the question. I don't even know if my article will be ever accepted at current of future congresses :D but I believe it's worth to discuss the subject

Consider the [2012 edition of this congress](https://www.springer.com/computer/communication+networks/book/978-3-642-29851-6): using the link to the "buy the book" page is not really the best option to enrich one's CV.

Instead one should be also able to reference articles in reference format.

i.e. A. `Author and B. Coauthor, “A new stackoverflow” in Proc. ICIN2012 (2012)` (the congress name is real ;-))

Mine is just an idea. What do you think about it?

Comment: "Since scientific papers don't usually have a home URL" — Wrong. Most, if not all journals have [DOIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) for the publication which uniquely identifies the paper (and is a non-expiring, unchanging URL). In your case you should wait till it is actually published before you get the DOI from the publisher. Besides, if it's not actually published, it shouldn't be on your CV, right?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Correct. Might as well be an answer.

Comment: @LoremIpsum I'm not "putting too much meat on fire" (if the proverb translates correctly...). I won't be able to update my CV until I get the paper published. Since this is my first, and since I never discussed this with my coauthor (who has lots of publications in his CV) I was just discussing a possible feature request. Thanks for the feedback and I believe that the discussion is automatically closed since all papers have URLs that careers can resolve. Your "answer" also *suggests* that I can input a dx.doi.org URL in the text field, while I've never tried.

Comment: @djechelon It is common on CVs to have no link and simply put "to appear".

Answer (score 1):

Right now, our focus is on credentials that can be cited on the web, so we won’t be allowing references in place of a URL. I hope your paper is accepted – sounds like it’s fairly standard that there would be a permanent URL for it.

You could also just create a page somewhere – on a blog or similar – which describes the work and its status in the meantime.