# Support for academic publications in Careers is woefully inadequate

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

I am a professional software developer, and I also have a large number of scientific publications, which are an essential part of my CV. I'm sure there are many others like me! Unfortunately, Stack Overflow Careers does not give me any good way of presenting these.

1. There is no specific section for 'academic publications'. A [previous discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166180/132073) suggests using the 'article' section. This just isn't the right place. They aren't comparable things. Papers usually take years of expert work, are peer-reviewed, and have stringent quality requirements. Blog posts... don't.
2. Papers are cited in specific ways, depending on the field. They are *never* cited by title with no authors or date listed. However that's what you get if you add a link to a paper using the 'add an article' button. There's no way to mention the journal either.
3. Articles on Careers expect summaries for context, but academic CVs almost never summarise individual papers. If they did, they would run to many pages. Instead a research area may be described in a separate section. The paper citations normally stand on their own.
4. Not all papers have an online reference. Some papers are not available online, others are still in preparation. Even when they do, the permanence of the link is questionable, depending on the journal. While online citations are nice, and should be encouraged, why are they *mandatory*?
5. Adding each paper individually to the CV is just too much work. I already have a list. If I could dump that list into a Markdown field, that would be perfect.

Listing my papers is not optional in my line of work. I really like Careers, and would like it to be the canonical place for my CV. But that isn't possible without giving me a place to correctly describe my academic contributions.

Comment: Importing from common citation formats would likely be needed to make this useful. If something like this would be implemented, it would also make it far easier to implement [real citation support in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature) as the mechanism from Careers could also be used on the actual SE sites.

Comment: Tag this question as a bug, it needs fixed.

Comment: Whilst this _does_ need action, that doesn't make it a bug. It's behaviour that's missing and needs to be there. It is not behaviour that was already added or intended to be there and yet is not currently working.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Can you edit your question, providing a few examples for reference? We're always looking to improve the CV and this seems like a great idea.

Comment: @Hynes - Thanks for the response. Can you clarify what sort of examples you are looking for? [Add explicit support for citing scientific literature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature) has a detailed description of how citation formats could work. The [standard options in Latex's natbib](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Citations) are a great example of the sorts of control that are useful.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Ok - yeah that helps. It's not something we'll get to right away, but as you can see - we're not declining the idea. It's a good suggestion that will benefit a lot of people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.